# How to solve GuzzleHttp redeclare error in Yii PHP?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, guzzle, guzzle-service-description

When I run my PHP Yii framework file, It results in the following error.

```
PHP Compile Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\Psr7\str() (previously declared in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PLATO/framework/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php:19)' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PLATO/protected/extensions/aws/GuzzleHttp/Psr7/functions.php:18 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError() #1 {main}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: have you upgraded to a newer version of guzzle recently?

Comment: No, I am actually setting the project & framework for the first time. I need to link my existing project with the Yii2 framework. When I link that & run my index.php file it displays the above error. Kindly help me with this issue. I'm new to PHP & Yii framework

Comment: your existing project has guzzlehttp?

Comment: yes. Kindly look into this question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660487/how-to-integrate-existing-project-with-yii-framework

Comment: Are you using composer for dependencies?

Comment: yes, I am using composer dependencies. I fixed the issue. I linked the Yii2 framework instead of Yii1 (My project setup). After that issue is fixed.